# SQL Server table and view show different values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a view that selects data from a table that is showing different data.

The table is `dbo.user`, the view is `dbo.users` (don't judge, I inherited this system).  The view is simply `select * from table`.

If I run the following statements:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM dbo.[User] WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY Field1;

SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM dbo.Users WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY Field1;
```

I get different values for one of the fields.  See the attached pic:

[image]

Any ideas how this happens?  The table is clustered, has a pk and unique index.

Comment: Alter your view to select the explicit column names instead of `*` and let us know if that fixes the problem.  Then never `SELECT *` again haha

Comment: Yes, altering the view fixes it, even if i don't change the definition and leave the select * in there.  My point is that this **shouldn't** happen, and this isn't the only view in the world like this.

Comment: Is your view created `WITH SCHEMABINDING` ? A `sp_refreshview viewName` will help as well.

Comment: There is no schemabinding on the view, and thanks, i know a sp_refreshview will also work, but I'm curious how the data in the view can be different from the data in the table.  That would lead me to believe that sql is caching the view results somewhere.  But I've never heard of views acting that way.

Comment: This happens when the underlying table has been changed but the view has not been refreshed in some way, such as sp_refreshview or dropping and recreating the view. *In other words:*  The view does not **automatically** know that the underlying columns were changed.

Comment: Ok, I can buy that, but where is the view caching the results from the table?  This isn't an indexed view.

Comment: It is not caching the results, it is just getting data from the wrong column.  Because it does not know that the columns have changed.

Comment: SQL isn't caching the data from the view, but it is caching the *metadata* about the underlying table. This is why your views should never use `SELECT *`. See https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Comment: @sqlpadawan check [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59575/8783) answer. You should use SCHEMABINDING when creating views.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers & options.  I will flip the view from select * to a list of fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a view is created it is bound to the metadata it needs in order to execute.

Note:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx

That says that `sp_refreshview`: "Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound view. Persistent metadata for a view can become outdated because of changes to the underlying objects upon which the view depends."

The outdated metadata binding causes the surprising "wrong" results.  Using schema-bound views is one way of avoiding the problem.

Read the link that Aaron Bertrand posted:

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Comment: you have a minor typo in sy_refreshview, but the change is too small to be an edit :)